# Is this a comparison construction: to redefine it as appropriate?

Tags: comparison

> •  Bat. It is well known that the quality of the RP bat vowel has changed since the 1930's. It is now more similar to "cardinal [a]" than it used to be. Hence Upton's choice of the [a] symbol. A more conservative line is to stick with the familiar symbol [æ], but **to redefine it as appropriate**. That, after all, is what we have all done with the [ʌ] symbol for the vowel of cut, blood, which used to be a back vowel but now has a central/front quality for which the most specific IPA symbol would probably be [ɐ] (turned a). A further argument in favour of retaining the symbol [æ] is that it preserves the parallelism with American and Australian English, in which the movement towards an opener quality has not taken place.
>   ([Prof. John Wells,University College London](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english-uni.htm)) * OP's emphasis

I understand the highlighted part as subject (*to redefine it*) plus predicate (*as appropriate*) construction: meaning, *to redefine it is as appropriate*. Is this right understanding? If it is, what does ‘*as*’ mean? Perchance, is it a part of comparison construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is whether *as appropriate* is **a)** an adjunct of manner modifying the verb *redefine*, or **b)** an object-oriented complement to the verb *redefine*, characterizing 'it' (the symbol [æ]) as "appropriate" now.

I think you understand this correctly as an adjunct. Prof. Wells is suggesting that the more conservative line is to

1. stick with the old symbol [æ], but
2. redefine, **in whatever manner is appropriate**, what /æ/ means when it is used to represent the phoneme in question.